# sharing spring security credentials in multi web module project

Tags: web, spring-security, war, ear

There are multiple web modules (wars) in an ear file. Each web-module has it's own spring security configuration.

Lets say, web_module_1.war and web_module_2.war

Now, when user is logged-in to web_module_1.war module and then navigate to url of web_module_2.war. In this case, user is redirected to login page of web_module_2.war even though he is logged in.

How to pass credentials of logged in user to web_module_2.war to avoid login page for logged in user.

Comment: are this modules deployed under same domain name, or two different hosts?

Comment: they are deployed under same host, packaged in an ear.

Comment: try RememberMe filter with cookie config and same secret token

Comment: Remember Me option is not a requirement. So, if I set Remember Me flag and then user closes the browser and comes back. He should have to login again.

Comment: just set empty expiration date, so cookie will expire on browser close